# how to make a python file expired or inaccessible within a certain time?

Tags: python

I've searched the internet and can't find what I mean. so here I want to make the python script expire or cannot be accessed within the specified time. Or maybe there is a function that I should add in the script? I'm not very good at English so I'm sorry for that. Hope you can understand what I mean

Comment: When you say expired or inaccessible within a specified time do you mean that regularly (once a day?) you want to disable access/execution of a python file?

Comment: Compare the time now against the (hardcoded?) expiry time.  If before the expire run the routine, if not, then refuse.  eg `datetime.datetime.now()` or `time.time()`

Comment: for example: "this file can be accessed/executed until the specified date or time" how do i change it in python code form?

Answer (score 0):

Append timestamp with your filename, so every time your script is executed

1. check if any file exist

- if exist extract timestamp from the filename
- check if the timestamp has expired

2. if file don't exist create a file eg: file_name_<datetime.now()>

```py
    import os
    from datetime import datetime
    
    
    filename="test_"
    folder = "log"
    expire_time = 2 # mins
    
    files = os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "/log")
    print(files)
    
    def get_current_str_unix_ts():
        return int(datetime.now().timestamp())
    
    def get_diff_btw_ts(unix_ts):
        print(unix_ts)
        converted_d1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(unix_ts))
        current_time = datetime.now()
        # get diff and cnvert into mins
        return  (current_time - converted_d1).total_seconds() / 60
    
    if len(files):
        for file in files:
            # check whether a file is expire
            date_from_filename = file.split("_")[1].removesuffix(".log")
            print("date_from_filename: ", date_from_filename)
            # get time_diff 
            time_diff = get_diff_btw_ts(date_from_filename)
            if time_diff > expire_time:
                print("expire the file")
    
    else:
        with open(f"{os.getcwd()}/log/{filename}{get_current_str_unix_ts()}.log", 'w') as f:
            pass
```

Comment: for example: "this file can be accessed/executed until the specified date or time" how do i change it in python code form?

Comment: Have updated the code in the above ans